JWT : how to handle refresh tokens in mobile applications?
In web, I would send the refresh token in an HTTP only cookie since it's more secure than sending it in the response body. As far as I know, mobile applications are not like the browser and cannot read cookies, so what's the best approach?
Also, on the client side, I'm thinking about storing the access token in memory and the refresh token on the device (AsyncStorage). Is this the right way?

Saving tokens such as access or refresh in AsyncStorage isn't secured, that's why you have to try an encrypted storage.
For that, I'm strongly recommending using:

IOS: react-native-keychain
Android: react-native-keystore

Happy coding!

If these are the same tokens you can get from inspecting your storage and network in a browser, you approach of using memory and async storage is completely fine.
